# Using Custom LLM to choose between doc retrieval (on SQL) or answering directly

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, large-language-model, llama, llama-index

Is there a way to make LLM automatically choose between using a function to get information (Retrieval QA) or answering question directly based on his knowledge.

Eg: Suppose I am making a airline bot, where customer provides his PNR/Email for verification. I have made it to make query to get the details of customer. (Used langchain)

But for further answering the question how can I make it answer directly to skip the document retrieval when it's not required.
Eg: I say I ask how he is doing. (Just a general question for llm, and to make bot for human like)

In this question doc retrieval is not required.

I have used langchain, for doc retrieval over structured data (SQL) and over unstructured data (pdfs of terms).

I am trying to use open source LLMs like Llama or any other (trying to avoid openai completely)

Answer (score 1):

in this scenario, you can use RunnableBranch in langchain:
and your question will route in 2 or more **LLM**

the first llm should identify the topic, if the topic is related to the document, llm should simply say `document` with no further words then you have to parse the output using langchain and check if the output was `document` pass it to the other LLM which have access to details to your customers.

here is how the first prompt should look like:

```js
const promptTemplate =
  PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(`Given the user question below, classify it as either being about \`docuemnt\`, \`airline\`, or \`Other\`.
                                     
Do not respond with more than one word.

<question>
{question}
</question>

Classification:`);
```

and after the question was answered you can parse it and choose your LLM for it:

```js
const model = new ChatAnthropic({
  modelName: "claude-2",
});

const classificationChain = RunnableSequence.from([
  promptTemplate,
  model,
  new StringOutputParser(),
]);

const classificationChainResult = await classificationChain.invoke({
  question: "how are you?",
});
console.log(classificationChainResult);
// console.log: Other
```

now that you know the topic, you can use `if-else` statements or whatever you like to do with it.

If you provide me with the code, I can offer more accurate assistance.